# Parse string having key=value pairs as JSON

Tags: javascript, json

My node app receives a series of strings in the format `"a=x b=y c=z"` (i.e. a string containing several space-separated `key=value` pairs).

What is the neatest way of converting such a string into a JSON object of the form `{a: x, b: y, c: z}`?

I'm betting that there's a one-line solution, but haven't managed to find it yet.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data is in the values? Strings? Numbers?

Comment: You say that you want a "JSON object" as result, but there is no such thing. JSON is a text format for representing data. Do you want the result to be JSON or an object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to replace the  with a `,` and an `=` with a `:`:

```
var jsonStr = '{' + str.replace(/ /g, ', ').replace(/=/g, ': ') + '}';
```

Or if you need quotes around the keys and values:

```
var jsonStr2 = '{"' + str.replace(/ /g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}';
```

---

`JSON.parse()` it if you need.

Sample output:

```
str:      a=x b=y c=z
jsonStr:  {a: x, b: y, c: z}
jsonStr2: {"a": "x", "b": "y", "c": "z"}
```

Comment: the keys would need to be quoted, as would the values to make proper json

Comment: But the OP needs it in the unquoted form.

Comment: Then it isn't json... also OP has "as JSON" in title but "JSON object" in question body (no such thing as a JSON object) so their example of what they want might be off (ie they want an Object, or they want actual JSON text)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Maybe `a` and `x` are already wrapped in quotes. Maybe they aren't. I've added the quoted version though.

Comment: Looks really good.  None of the keys are already wrapped in quotes, but awkwardly some (but not all) of the values *are* already wrapped in quotes.

Comment: If the unquoted values are integers (i.e you do not need any extra quotes around values in the JSON), you can modify the second version to only wrap quotes around keys.
Something like this perhaps: `'{"' + str.replace(/ /g, ', "').replace(/=/g, '": ') + '}';`

Comment: Otherwise, remove all the quotes from the original string(using `str.replace(/"/g, '')`), and follow the steps in the answer. ;)

Comment: The latter is good, since the unquoted values are a mix of integers and strings.  So I've settled on `var json = JSON.parse('{"' + logItem.message.replace(/"/g, '').replace(/ /g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}');` which seems to be working well.  Thanks.

Comment: I discovered that some of the already-quoted values had spaces in them, which were being replaced with `", "` by the above scheme.  So I'm now using a slightly more sophisticated scheme that only replaces space that is *not* inside quotes.  In doing so, I need to preserve the quotes until the end, and then just replace any double quotes with single quotes: `JSON.parse(('{"' + message.replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}').replace(/""/g, '"'));`

Comment: A further refinement to deal with situation where there is a `=` followed by nothing, e.g. `key1= key2=val`... try `JSON.parse(('{"' + message.replace(/=(\s|$)/g, '="" ').replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}').replace(/""/g, '"'));`

Comment: @drmbrewer I made it a community wiki. Feel free to edit the answer, or create another of your own.

Comment: OK, so that I could expand on my comment above, I've added another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32154243/4070848

Answer (score 3):

Building on [John Bupit's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127023/4070848), I have made a couple of further enhancements to end up with the following (the string being parsed being in `message`):

`var json = JSON.parse(('{"' + message.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/=(?=\s|$)/g, '="" ').replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}').replace(/""/g, '"'));`

Basically the scheme is as follows:

1. First `replace()`: trim off any leading or trailing whitespace -- equivalent to `trim()`
2. Second `replace()`: add double quotes (empty string) for any value that is completely missing (e.g. `key1= key2=val` goes to `key1="" key2=val`).
3. Third `replace()`: replace each space (which acts as a delimiter) with `", "`, but *not* where the space is within double quotes (i.e. part of a string value).
4. Fourth `replace()`: replace each `=` with `": "`
5. Wrap the entire string up as follows: `{"..."}`
6. Finally, replace any double quotes `""` created by the above steps (because the value string was already wrapped in quotes in `message`) with single quotes `"`
7. Even more finally, run `JSON.parse()` over the result.

The above scheme should cope with missing values, with some values being quoted and some unquoted, and with spaces within value strings, e.g. something like `a= b="x" c="y y" d=z`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't get nested objects in that format :

```
var sample = 'a=x b=y c=z';
var newobj = {};
sample.split(' ').forEach(function (value) {
    var keypair = value.split('=');
    newobj[keypair[0]] = keypair[1];
});
console.dir(newobj);
```

What this does is split on every white-space and push to an array, and the array is looped and each item in array is split again to get each key-value pair which is assigned to the newobj.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple function that will do the trick

```
function stringToObj (string) {
  var obj = {}; 
  var stringArray = string.split(' '); 
  for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){ 
    var kvp = stringArray[i].split('=');
    if(kvp[1]){
     obj[kvp[0]] = kvp[1] 
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newstr = ""
for kvp in @value.split(" ")
  newstr += kvp.replace(/=/,'":"').replace(/^/, '"').replace(/$/, '"').replace(/\"\"/,'" "')

newstr = newstr.replace(/\"\"/g, '","')
jsn = JSON.parse('{' + newstr + '}')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple online tool for similar need: https://superal.github.io/online-tools/

**Use cases**:
To transfer key:value pairs copied from chrome network requests(form data or query string parameters) or postman headers key-value(in bulk edit style) to json format.

**For example**:
key:value pairs

```
platform:2
limit:10
start_time:1521561600
end_time:1522080000
offset:0
```

to json format

```
{
  "platform": "2",
  "limit": "10",
  "start_time": "1521561600",
  "end_time": "1522080000",
  "offset": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be parsed (converted to json) using the help of this npm **athena-struct-parser** package.

For more information about the package -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/athena-struct-parser

**Sample Nodejs Code**

```
var parseStruct =require('athena-struct-parser') ;
var str = '{description=Check the Primary key count of TXN_EVENT table in Oracle, datastore_order=1, zone=yellow, aggregation_type=count, updatedcount=0, updatedat=[2021-06-09T02:03:20.243Z]}'
var parseObj = parseStruct(str)
console.log(parseObj);
```

**Sample string with **key=value** format taken**

```
   {description=Check the Primary key count of TXN_EVENT table in Oracle, datastore_order=1, zone=yellow, aggregation_type=count, updatedcount=0, updatedat=[2021-06-09T02:03:20.243Z]}
```

**Result Parsed output**

```
{
  description: 'Check the Primary key count of TXN_EVENT table in Oracle',
  datastore_order: '1',
  zone: 'yellow',
  aggregation_type: 'count',
  updatedcount: '0',
  updatedat: [ '2021-06-09T02:03:20.004Z' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach leveraging [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like so:

```js
const input = "a=x b=y c=z";

const queryString = input.replaceAll(" ", "&");
const query = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const output = Object.fromEntries(query);

console.log(output);
```

Breakdown:

The `URLSearchParams` constructor takes a string of key-value pairs joined by "&" as it's argument, and parses it into a `URLSearchParams` object instance. So to use this, the space separators in the original input need to be replaced with a "&" character.

The `URLSearchParams` instance we have after parsing is an *iterable*, so we can  transform it into a plain Object with `Object.fromEntries()`.

It's not too bad as a one-liner either:

```js
const input = "a=x b=y c=z";

const output = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(input.replaceAll(" ", "&")));
```